# Generate Signature for API call with php

Tags: php, api

I have an API documentation. I am having issues when creating the signature the request. I have the following procedures on how to create the signature. Can someone help me out with a example from the procedure below:

Generate signature To create the signature

```
Create the canonical zed query string that you need later in this procedure:
    Sort the UTF-8 query string components by parameter name with natural byte ordering. The parameters can come from the GET URI or from the POST body (when Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded).
    URL encode the parameter name and values
    Concatinate name and values to a single string (eg. var1value1var2value2)
Calculate an RFC 2104-compliant HMAC with the string you just created, your API Access Key as the key, and SHA1 as the hash algorithm.
Make the resulting value base64 encoded.
Use the Resulting value as the value of the Signature request parameter
```

Edit:

Here is a sample output in the documentation:

https://domain.com/api.php?action=checkDomain&version=20090622&keyId=123456 &name=glo0000w.com&signature=fvatTFVwRNF1cyH%2Fj%2Flaig8QytY%3D

Below is what I tried to do, but it did not work

```
<?php  
$sig = urlencode('actioncheckDomainversion20090622keyId123456nameglo0000w.com');
$sig = hash_hmac('sha1', $sig, '123456');
$sig = base64_encode($sig);
?>
```

Can someone please help me implement the procedure to generate the signature with php? thank you.

Comment: You left out "Make the resulting value base64 encoded".  `$sig = base64_encode($sig);`

Comment: duplicate of the question you asked earlier

Comment: @RocketHazmat I added it and still get error:  Wrong request signing UPL-TYQTSBHIYGRFHKXEPJNPELGY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you didn't sort your parameters by key like you were supposed to.

```
$p = array(
    'action' => 'checkDomain',
    'version' => '20090622',
    'keyId' => 123456,
    'name' => 'glo0000w.com',
);

ksort($p);
$string = '';
foreach($p as $oneKey=>$oneValue)
    $string .= urlencode($oneKey) . urlencode($oneValue);
```

Your other problem is in your call to `hash_hmac()`.  By default, it returns a hex string and there would be no point in base64-encoding that.  Also, the resulting output is way longer than the example.  I'm pretty sure  this is an error.

Instead, you want to produce a binary output using the optional fourth parameters [per the hash_hmac docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) and base64 encode *that* value:

```
$hash = hash_hmac('sha1', $string, '123456', true);
$sig = base64_encode($hash);
```

Finally, I suspect you may be using the wrong access key for signing.  You used the `keyId` value, which is *always* different than the `accessKey`. (Except possibly in examples.)